# Where are the EmbeddedChart setOptions options?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am using the [EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder) to create charts dynamically, which is working fine. Basic example:

```
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Charts');
 var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0)
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.AREA)
    .addRange(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data').getRange("A1:A10"))
    .build();
 sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

However I need to customize the charts using the `setOption` method. [The documentation says](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setoptionoption-value):

> Sets advanced options for this chart. See
>   https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference for
>   what options are available.

But following the link they give (/chart/interactive/docs/reference), the only thing I see is this:

[image]

Trying to find `vAxis` doesn't lead anywhere. [Looking at another page on advanced chart customization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts), once again I see examples but not the reference:

```
var options = {
  width: 400,
  height: 240,
  title: 'Toppings I Like On My Pizza',
  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
};
```

**Where is the list of all available options for the `setOption` method?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find options for various chart types on the [Guides](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/) page (instead of the Reference page) of the link you posted. 
For example, options for Bar chart type are here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options

Comment: hmm, was on that very page, missed it :(